# Unable to find device in opencl using beignet

Tags: opencl, gpu

I am trying to run opencl using beignet

https://askubuntu.com/questions/412009/open-cl-in-intel

My system configuration is
Intel HD Graphics 5500
NVIDIA GeForce 830M (2 GB DDR3 dedicated)

When I run the following code:

```
    // HelloWorld.cpp
    //
   //    This is a simple example that demonstrates basic OpenCL setup and
   //    use.

    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>

    #ifdef __APPLE__
    #include <OpenCL/cl.h>
    #else
    #include <CL/cl.h>
    #endif

    ///
    //  Constants
   //
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;

   ///
  //  Create an OpenCL context on the first available platform using
  //  either a GPU or CPU depending on what is available.
  //
 cl_context CreateContext()
  {
            cl_int errNum;
      cl_uint numPlatforms;
      cl_platform_id firstPlatformId;
      cl_context context = NULL;

      // First, select an OpenCL platform to run on.  For this example, we
      // simply choose the first available platform.  Normally, you would
      // query for all available platforms and select the most appropriate one.
      errNum = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &firstPlatformId, &numPlatforms);
      if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS || numPlatforms <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to find any OpenCL platforms." <<      std::endl;
        return NULL;
     }

// Next, create an OpenCL context on the platform.  Attempt to
// create a GPU-based context, and if that fails, try to create
// a CPU-based context.
cl_context_properties contextProperties[] =
{
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
    (cl_context_properties)firstPlatformId,
    0
};
context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
                                      NULL, NULL, &errNum);
if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cout << "Could not create GPU context, trying CPU..." << std::endl;
    context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,
                                      NULL, NULL, &errNum);
    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create an OpenCL GPU or CPU context." << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}

return context;
    }

   ///
    //  Create a command queue on the first device available on the
    //  context
   //
   cl_command_queue CreateCommandQueue(cl_context context,      cl_device_id *device)
    {
       cl_int errNum;
cl_device_id *devices;
cl_command_queue commandQueue = NULL;
size_t deviceBufferSize = -1;

// First get the size of the devices buffer
errNum = clGetContextInfo(context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, 0, NULL, &deviceBufferSize);
if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed call to clGetContextInfo(...,GL_CONTEXT_DEVICES,...)";
    return NULL;
}

if (deviceBufferSize <= 0)
{
    std::cerr << "No devices available.";
    return NULL;
}

// Allocate memory for the devices buffer
devices = new cl_device_id[deviceBufferSize / sizeof(cl_device_id)];
errNum = clGetContextInfo(context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, deviceBufferSize, devices, NULL);
if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    delete [] devices;
    std::cerr << "Failed to get device IDs";
    return NULL;
}

// In this example, we just choose the first available device.  In a
// real program, you would likely use all available devices or choose
// the highest performance device based on OpenCL device queries
commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, NULL);
if (commandQueue == NULL)
{
    delete [] devices;
    std::cerr << "Failed to create commandQueue for device 0";
    return NULL;
}

*device = devices[0];
delete [] devices;
return commandQueue;
  }

    ///
    //  Create an OpenCL program from the kernel source file
    //
    cl_program CreateProgram(cl_context context, cl_device_id device, const char* fileName)
     {
cl_int errNum;
cl_program program;

std::ifstream kernelFile(fileName, std::ios::in);
if (!kernelFile.is_open())
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file for reading: " << fileName << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << kernelFile.rdbuf();

std::string srcStdStr = oss.str();
const char *srcStr = srcStdStr.c_str();
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
                                    (const char**)&srcStr,
                                    NULL, NULL);
if (program == NULL)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to create CL program from source." << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

errNum = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    // Determine the reason for the error
    char buildLog[16384];
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                          sizeof(buildLog), buildLog, NULL);

    std::cerr << "Error in kernel: " << std::endl;
    std::cerr << buildLog;
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    return NULL;
}

return program;
    }

 ///
//  Create memory objects used as the arguments to the kernel
//  The kernel takes three arguments: result (output), a (input),
//  and b (input)
//
bool CreateMemObjects(cl_context context, cl_mem memObjects[3],
                  float *a, float *b)
{
memObjects[0] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                               sizeof(float) * ARRAY_SIZE, a, NULL);
memObjects[1] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                               sizeof(float) * ARRAY_SIZE, b, NULL);
memObjects[2] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                               sizeof(float) * ARRAY_SIZE, NULL, NULL);

if (memObjects[0] == NULL || memObjects[1] == NULL || memObjects[2] == NULL)
{
    std::cerr << "Error creating memory objects." << std::endl;
    return false;
}

return true;
  }

    ///
    //  Cleanup any created OpenCL resources
    //
   void Cleanup(cl_context context, cl_command_queue commandQueue,
         cl_program program, cl_kernel kernel, cl_mem memObjects[3])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (memObjects[i] != 0)
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[i]);
}
if (commandQueue != 0)
    clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);

if (kernel != 0)
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);

if (program != 0)
    clReleaseProgram(program);

if (context != 0)
    clReleaseContext(context);

  }

    ///
   //   main() for HelloWorld example
   //
  int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
cl_context context = 0;
cl_command_queue commandQueue = 0;
cl_program program = 0;
cl_device_id device = 0;
cl_kernel kernel = 0;
cl_mem memObjects[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
cl_int errNum;

// Create an OpenCL context on first available platform
context = CreateContext();
if (context == NULL)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to create OpenCL context." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

// Create a command-queue on the first device available
// on the created context
commandQueue = CreateCommandQueue(context, &device);
if (commandQueue == NULL)
{
    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);
    return 1;
}

// Create OpenCL program from HelloWorld.cl kernel source
program = CreateProgram(context, device, "HelloWorld.cl");
if (program == NULL)
{
    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);
    return 1;
}

// Create OpenCL kernel
kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "hello_kernel", NULL);
if (kernel == NULL)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to create kernel" << std::endl;
    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);
    return 1;
}

// Create memory objects that will be used as arguments to
// kernel.  First create host memory arrays that will be
// used to store the arguments to the kernel
float result[ARRAY_SIZE];
float a[ARRAY_SIZE];
float b[ARRAY_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    a[i] = (float)i;
    b[i] = (float)(i * 2);
}

if (!CreateMemObjects(context, memObjects, a, b))
{
    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);
    return 1;
}

// Set the kernel arguments (result, a, b)
errNum = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjects[0]);
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjects[1]);
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjects[2]);
if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cerr << "Error setting kernel arguments." << std::endl;
    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);
    return 1;
}

size_t globalWorkSize[1] = { ARRAY_SIZE };
size_t localWorkSize[1] = { 1 };

// Queue the kernel up for execution across the array
errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, NULL,
                                globalWorkSize, localWorkSize,
                                0, NULL, NULL);
if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cerr << "Error queuing kernel for execution." << std::endl;
    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);
    return 1;
}

// Read the output buffer back to the Host
errNum = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE,
                             0, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float), result,
                             0, NULL, NULL);
if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cerr << "Error reading result buffer." << std::endl;
    Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);
    return 1;
}

// Output the result buffer
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    std::cout << result[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Executed program succesfully." << std::endl;
Cleanup(context, commandQueue, program, kernel, memObjects);

return 0;
}
```

I always get the output:

```
 Number of available platforms: 1
 Platform names:
     [0] Experiment Intel Gen OCL Driver [Selected]
 Number of devices available for each type:
     CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU: 0
     CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU: 0
     CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR: 0

    *** Detailed information for each device ***
```

I tried various opencl codes and none of them works properly.Why are the devices not being found and what is the solution?

Comment: Your code looks ok. This is most likely an issue with your graphics card driver.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run clinfo utility?

You can get clinfo for your linux and then run it. It provides a list of every platform and devices found. If you can't get your device listed by clinfo, you won't have it listed by your program.

It looks like you have a Nvidia Optimus computer, and it is very bad because Nvidia does not provide official support for Optimus on Linux. However, at least your Intel CPU shoule be recognized.

If you can't get it listed, you might lack the dri driver for your vendor (nvidia).